# Retrieve Text file content using Bitbucket server rest APIs in Java JsonNode format

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am trying to use the bitbucket server rest API to fetch file content(.json file) from a bitbucket repository in a Java spring boot Application but the response is not as expected.

**Content in the file *meta.json***

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

**API used**
https://bitbucket.domain.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/my-project/repos/my-repo/browse/path/to/meta.json

**Java snippet used to get file content**

```
String url = "https://bitbucket.domain.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/my-project/repos/my-repo/browse/path/to/meta.json";
JsonNode bucketData = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, JsonNode.class).getBody();
```

**Actual output:**

```
{
    "lines": [
        {
            "text": "{"
        },
        {
            "text": "  \"key1\": \"value1\","
        },
        {
            "text": "  \"key2\": \"value2\""
        },
        {
            "text": "}"
        }
    ],
    "start": 0,
    "size": 4,
    "isLastPage": true
}
```

Whereas the output I want is the following

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

So I can convert it to JsonNode and use it.

**Observation**

While hitting the repo url with *?raw* param (https://bitbucket.domain.com/projects/my-project/repos/my-repo/browse/path/to/meta.json?raw) I was getting the excepted output in text format, not json format. I also tried using the same url in my spring boot application but that didnt work either.

Any suggestion on how can I get the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able fix this issue, by using [Unirest](http://kong.github.io/unirest-java/)

The following syntax was used

```
String url = "https://bitbucket.domain.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/my-project/repos/my-repo/browse/path/to/meta.json";
HttpResponse<T> response = Unirest.get(url).headers(headers).asObject(responseClass);
JsonNode bucketData = response.getBody();
```